# How to make textboxes auto populate from a file based on input into another textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows

I am writing a c# gui where I have a form to get information about inventory from a store and I would like it to link when I have user input into the UPC box hit Ok and the rest auto fill from a microsoft access file. Is there any way to do this? I don't have any code besides the auto-generated code by double clicking the button and the text box.

Comment: So what have you tried? Your question is a bit broad. There are tens of ways of ways of doing this. Google C# and Access. If you tell us what version of .net and VS you are using, we'll be able to help more, the wizards have changed considerably.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010. And I haven't really tried anything yet I am just getting started and am unsure if doing this is even possible. I am pretty new to C#.

Comment: Not only possible but probable. CRUD applications are two a penny, unfortunately so are approaches. Any starter C# book or tutorial will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the controls where you'll display your information to the form. Then you would need to write code to look up the information in the database file, and once you have that, fill in the controls that are already on the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read the data from a Microsoft Access DB file then something like this will return the data that you need. It's important to know What you are trying to get though. Something similiar to this will return the data. Then from there fill where that data needs to go.

```
string ConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=
                                     C:\DatabaseNameGoesHere.mdb";
            OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(ConString);
            OleDbCommand Command = Con.CreateCommand();

            // create the DataSet
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            // clear the grids data source
            PlaceToPutTheData.DataSource = null;

            // open the connection
            Con.Open();

            // run the query
            Command.CommandText = "Select the data from the table you need;
            OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
            Adapter.Fill(ds);

            // close the connection
            Con.Close();

            // set the grid's data source
            PlaceToPutTheData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Your question is a little vague so it's hard to give you the direct answer, but hopefully this will give you a start and help.